# What does add to index mean in git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using eclipse and I set up git on 3 different pcs.
The difference to my computer and the 2 other computers is that they have to click "add to index" before they are able to commit. I don't have to click this before I commit. Why is there a difference? is it that I got an older version of git? I want to know why, because adding files to the index takes quite some time on the other pcs and I don't really like that, because I don't have to on my pc.

Comment: Are you using eGit (i.e. Eclipse's `git` look-alike)? Or actual `git`? Or perhaps that's the difference?

Comment: Uhm, I installed the thing in eclipse, help>install new software and then this: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/

Comment: Ok, that's not really `git`, it's `eGit`. But I don't know if that's the difference.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait for other people to help you answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means exactly what it [means on the command line](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). You can *always* commit, even from the command line, but it will only ever act on what's been added to the index.

Comment: But you only have to add all the files you want to commit once to the index, right? so you've made a project and you want it to commit for the first time ever, then you press add to index, so it takes the whole project and then you press commit. if you change something in the project then you only have to commit it, right?

Comment: No. "It only adds the content of the specified file(s) *at the time* the add command is run" -https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add

Comment: So before every commit I have to use the add command to add the changes to the "waiting list" to be commited?

Comment: Okay, but it looks like that on my pc it does that automatically, is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The only thing wrong with this answer is that *OP is not using the command line*. OP is using eGit in Eclipse. And in Eclipse, the UI allows one to skip the Add step (by using checkboxes in the commit dialog).

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Sorry for the late answer, but I think that that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx : You should accept this answer, both the question and answer have been helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot about this question. Pretty weird to read it again after about 3 years.